# Ampersand issue in w3c validator and search engine

Tags: php, html

I'm using more than one ampersand in my url, see my link below

```
http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&vid=3975&auth=many
```

When i try to validate in w3c validator it showed hundreds of error because of this & (ampersand).

After that i read some post in here and i got the solution too. 
Instead of using (`&`) If i use (`&amp;`) w3c validates fine.

But the problem now is in search Engine. Instead of taking (`&`). it is taking like the below link

```
http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&amp;vid=3975&amp;auth=many
```

if you copy paste the above link in the address bar it will take you to the wrong page!. Please help how can i solve it.

Comment: Where exactly do these links show up? Can you show the originating page?

Comment: in which search engine are the links wrong? can you provide a link? major search engines usually handle ampersands correctly..

Comment: it's long back i tried to use &amp. Yahoo read this & as &amp; . Google is ok

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error in your code but since we cannot see any of it I think the most important bit is to understand why the W3C validator complaints about raw `&`.

1. The HTML syntax contains two basic elements: tags (e.g. `<strong>`) and entities (e.g. `&euro;`). Everything else is displayed as-is.
2. Browsers are expected to *ignore* errors.

When you type unknown or invalid tags, the browser will do its best to guess and fix it (you are probably aware of that already):

```
<p>Hello <i>world</b>!</p>
```

... will render as:

```
<p>Hello <i>world</i>!</p>
```

But the same happens when you type an unknown or invalid entity. In your example, there are two invalid entities:

```
http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&vid=3975&auth=many
                                                ^^^^     ^^^^^
```

However, it *works* because the browser is clever enough to figure out the real URL. Only the validator complaints because it is a tool specifically designed to find errors.

Now, imagine I want to use HTML to write an HTML tutorial and I want to explain the `<strong>` tag. If I just type `<strong>example</strong>`, the browser will display **example**. I need to encode the `<` symbol so it no longer has a special meaning:

```
&lt;strong&gt;example&lt;/strong&gt;
```

Now the browser displays <strong>example</strong>, which is precisely the content I want to show.

The same happens with your URL. Since `&` is part of the entity syntax, when I want to insert a literal `&` I need to encode it as well:

```
Barnes &amp; Noble
```

... will render as Barnes & Noble. Please note that this is only a syntactic trick to insert plain text into a HTML document. Your document shows Barnes & Noble. to all effects, no matter how you encode it. So when you replace `&` with `&amp;` in your URL, you are *not changing* your URL, you are just encoding it.

If search engines are spidering the wrong URL, that means you have actually *changed* your URL rather than just encoding it, so the source code is:

```
http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&amp;amp;vid=3975&amp;amp;auth=many
```

... and renders as:

```
http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&amp;vid=3975&amp;auth=many
```

This can happen, for instance, if you encode twice:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&vid=3975&auth=many';
$url = htmlspecialchars($url);
$url = htmlspecialchars($url);
echo $url;
```

... or:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.theonlytutorials.com/video.php?cat=55&amp;vid=3975&amp;auth=many';
$url = htmlspecialchars($url); // Oops: URL is already encoded!
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you made a typo error, it must be `&amp;` not `&ampamp;`

Comment: Actually its &amp only. but when i create question it was showing (&)

Comment: @agurchand - If the question is wrong, edit it until it's right. You have a toolbar button to format code and a preview panel.

Comment: question edited. now it's showing correctly. tell me the solution please

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - You're right, is there anyway to decode or encode the url!